# Migrations in Identity with Multiple Data Access Layers

Tags: asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I have an application that consists of a console app that runs in the background and a web app as an interface to the data. Because many database functions are used by the two applications I have a data access layer (DAL) that is used to access the database and a data model layer (DML) created from the database. I am using a code-first solution and have enabled migrations on the DML. However, I am beginning to implement user logins using Identity Framework and this is obviously on the web app side of things. Can I enable migrations in this app - the Identity models/data will be located in the same database as the other data. Just wondering if I’m going to screw things up by trying to enable migrations on the same database from different application? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears I can add migrations to the same database from different projects. Very pleased. I’d still appreciate any guidance or “don’t do this” comments.